# can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List' in flutter

Tags: flutter, charts

I got error in below code , on widget:

> The argument type 'List<Series<dynamic, dynamic>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<Series<dynamic, String*>*>*'.

This is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
// ignore: import_of_legacy_library_into_null_safe
import 'package:charts_flutter/flutter.dart' as charts;

class SimpleBarChart extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<charts.Series> seriesList;
  final bool? animate;

  SimpleBarChart(this.seriesList, {this.animate});

  factory SimpleBarChart.withSampleData() {
    return new SimpleBarChart(
      _createSampleData(),
      // Disable animations for image tests.
      animate: false,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new charts.BarChart(
      seriesList, //error this
      animate: animate,
    );
  }

  /// Create one series with sample hard coded data.
  static List<charts.Series<OrdinalSales, String>> _createSampleData() {
    final data = [
      new OrdinalSales('2014', 5),
      new OrdinalSales('2015', 25),
      new OrdinalSales('2016', 100),
      new OrdinalSales('2017', 75),
    ];

    return [
      new charts.Series<OrdinalSales, String>(
        id: 'Sales',
        colorFn: (_, __) => charts.MaterialPalette.blue.shadeDefault,
        domainFn: (OrdinalSales sales, _) => sales.year,
        measureFn: (OrdinalSales sales, _) => sales.sales,
        data: data,
      )
    ];
  }
}

class OrdinalSales {
  final String year;
  final int sales;

  OrdinalSales(this.year, this.sales);
}
```

Is my code not compatible with the chart plugin above?

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new charts.BarChart(
      seriesList, // this
      animate: animate,
    );
```

}

How to solve this?

Comment: try instead of this List<charts.Series<OrdinalSales, String>>  ,  List<charts.Series<OrdinalSales, dynamic>> . Change String part to dynamic when initializing lists

Comment: where am i the code

Comment: static List<charts.Series<OrdinalSales, String>> and new charts.Series<OrdinalSales, String>(

Comment: I have tried this but there is still an error notification